# Migrating spring to spring boot controller not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jsp

I have an existing application built on Spring 4.3.20 and Hibernate 3.6, we were using `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` in XML configuration for controller mapping and it is working fine.

I am trying to use spring boot 1.5.17.RELEASE for compatibility with current spring version 4.3.20-RELEASE. Now after solving all the compilation and deployment issues, I cannot see my existing controller working fine with browser/POST/GET mapping. It always shows 404 error.

I checked the logs at the time of deployment and found that the mapping is done properly, get below in the logs:

```
2019-06-03 12:39:26.333  INFO 15630 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

I also created one separate controller with annotation(without `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping`) and its mapping is done properly as per logs and it works fine

```
2019-06-03 12:32:10.437  INFO 26049 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] .w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/testc] onto handler 'testController'
2019-06-03 12:32:10.437  INFO 26049 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] .w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/testc.*] onto handler 'testController'
2019-06-03 12:32:10.437  INFO 26049 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] .w.s.m.a.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/testc/] onto handler 'testController'
2019-06-03 12:32:10.583  INFO 26049 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/testc],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.krawler.spring.TestController.test()
2019-06-03 12:32:16.898  INFO 26049 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/testc],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.krawler.spring.TestController.test()
2019-06-04 16:55:12.448  INFO 13811 --- [nio-8084-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/AuthHandler/*.do] onto handler 'authHandlercontroller'
```

I tried with @Controller with jsp page and it works fine but not the existing one where we are using ModelAndView.

*Controller class*

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("testc")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    public String test(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

*/WEB-INF/jsp/test.jsp*

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

*AuthHandlreController*

```
public ModelAndView verifyUserLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
.....
        return new ModelAndView("jsonView_ex", "model", jobj.toString());
    }
```

*Bean for jsonView_ex*

```
<bean name="jsonView_ex" class="com.mycompany.views.JsonView_ex">
        <property name="contentType">
            <value>text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

*JsonView_ex.java*

```
public class JsonView_ex extends AbstractView {

    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map map,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String model = (String) map.get("model");

        try {
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(model);
            if (jobj.has("msg")) {
                if (jobj.getString("msg").toLowerCase().contains("system failure:")) {
                    jobj.remove("msg");
                    jobj.put("msg", "Some problem occurred while performing the operation. Please try again later.");
                    model = jobj.toString();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            model = (String) map.get("model");
        }
        // write the XML data to the response
        response.getOutputStream().write(model.getBytes());
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    }
}
```

`TestController` works fine and not the `AuthHandlerController` also the

The issue seems to be with view only but not sure how to solve it.

Comment: It seems, `spring` is not able to find the `test.jsp` file. Is it on the right path?

Comment: I tried with ModelAndView also by returning json and still same problem.

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations

Comment: First of all remember you had a working application and thus a working configuration. Don't throw away that configuration instead use it!. Use `@Import` (for Javas Config) or `@ImportResource` (for XML) to load your existing configuration. (Don't upgrade AND modify your config at the same time!). Next you are using JSP which have quite some limitations in a JAR setup so you will need to stick with a WAR setup (basically you should only introduce dependencies, and load your confiugration as a first step!).

Comment: I got TestController working with chnaging the jsp path but still facing issue with abstract view, please check updated post

Comment: As stated, you have a working configuration with  your application. Use that. Don't do 10 things at once, focus on 1 thing. You are now all over the place (is it idependencies, my java config, spring boot, .... ). Your xml configuration can (and should) still be loaded. That was your working software. If that works, then start removing parts of the XML (like datasource, entitymanagerfactory and use the spring Boot auto-config, finally port the last part to `@Bean`s in `@Configuration` classes. Take baby-steps, you are trying to take giants leaps.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Yes, I am only doing one thing at a time, I am not playing currently with JPA, entitymanager etc. Just trying that my existing(working) workspace should use spring boot and controller should work fine with xml configuration, though they are shown in logs and also the beans are created properly I was hoping that the method should work fine with controller but its not working as mentioned above. The only thing I am trying to do is that controllers are invoked properly.

Comment: You might think that you are focussing on one thing, but this is merely a symptom of doing/forgetting things. You probably have/had a `web.xml` which contained things to be loaded. You moved everything over, already moved parts of your XML configuration to java config (judging from  your startup logs). Also the fact that you had compilation issues is weird, as if you stick with the same versions you shouldn't have those. (Maybe I should really finish that blog post about moving to Spring Boot). Currently I don't really know specifically how to help as there are a lot of things going on here.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thanks for spending time on it, but I am still using web.xml configuration for dispatcher servlet. The logs shows for TestController which I created for testing purpose. The issue seems to be here is that abstractView JsonView_ex not working when put it as view name in ModelAndView, it shows 404 error for the same.

Comment: If you are using `web.xml` you aren't yet using Spring Boot (unless you are using Spring Boot Legacy). If you have both a `web.xml` and `@SpringBootApplication`annoated class (which also extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` you end up with multiple `DispatcherServlet` instances). So as we don't know what you did and didn't do, it is hard too tell where to point you next. Looks like you have 2 things going on.

Comment: If the only thing you did was use Spring Boot starter dependencies for dependency managemment things should still work the same. If you added an `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class which also extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` you basically have duplicated the `DispatcherServlet` instances leading to interesting results I suppose.

Comment: @M.Deinum - For more clarification I have raised the same in another post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457849/old-dispatcher-servlet-not-working-in-spring-boot-after-migration

Answer (score 0):

Springboot has limitations when using jsp as the view resolver when using `jar` as the packaging. In your case make sure that you are generating a `war` file, use the following in POM :

**pom.xml**

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Put the above tag just below the `<version>` tag in main pom.And also make sure to put your jsp files in the folder `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp` or basically under webapps.

Make sure you have the following dependencies added in pom for compiling the jsp :

```
<!-- JSTL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- To compile JSP files -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and also in `application.properties` or `application.yml` whichever you are using put :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Comment: I am doing that but issue is different please see updated post