# Old dispatcher servlet not working in spring boot after migration

Tags: spring-boot

I have an existing application built on Spring 4.3.20 and Hibernate 3.6, we were using `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` in XML configuration for controller mapping and it is working fine.

I started with smaller steps and without any changes I just moved my maven project to spring-boot dependencies only (without `@SpringBootApplication` annotated file) and it all worked fine.
Now I started moving my `web.xml` content to `SpringBootApplication` file but it didn't work, not sure what am I missing.

**Controller**

```
public class AuthController extends MultiActionController {
public ModelAndView test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
        return new ModelAndView("jsonView","model",<data in string>,);
    }
}
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans>
    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>                
                <prop key="AuthController/*.do">AuthController</prop>
</props>
        </property>
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="openSessionInViewInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>    
            </bean>

</beans>
```

**views.xml**

```
<bean name="jsonView" class="com.mycompany.views.JsonView">
        <property name="contentType">
            <value>text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**JsonView.java**

```
public class JsonView extends AbstractView {
    boolean validSession = true;

    public void setValidSession(boolean validSession) {
        this.validSession = validSession;
    }

    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map map,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String model = (String) map.get("model");

        try {
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(model);
            if (jobj.has("msg")) {
                if (jobj.getString("msg").toLowerCase().contains("system failure:")) {
                    jobj.remove("msg");
                    jobj.put("msg", "Some problem occurred while performing the operation. Please try again later.");
                    model = jobj.toString();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            model = (String) map.get("model");
        }
        model = "{\"valid\":" + this.validSession + ",\"data\":" + model + ",\"success\":true}";
        response.getOutputStream().write(model.getBytes());
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    }
```

**web.xml** content which we have removed for SpringBootApplication

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:config/applicationContextList.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:config/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**SpringBootApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@ImportResource("classpath*:config/applicationContextList.xml")
public class MainSpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MainSpringBootApplication.class);
    }
@Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new DispatcherServlet();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet());
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("contextClass","org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext");
        params.put("contextConfigLocation","classpath:config/dispatcher-servlet.xml");
                registration.setInitParameters(params);
        registration.addUrlMappings("*.do");
        registration.addUrlMappings("/props/*");
        return registration;
    }
```

**applicationContext-view.xml**

```
<bean id="xmlViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" /> 
        <property name = "location">
         <value>/WEB-INF/views.xml</value>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

**applicationContextList.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
    <import resource="applicationContext.xml" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-view.xml" />   
</beans>
```

When the js calls `AuthController.test.do` then it gives 404 error whereas was working fine without SpringBootApplication and only `web.xml`

I get below log when I execute the required service:

```
2019-06-05 16:48:35.893 DEBUG 26901 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/Accounting/AuthController/test.do]
2019-06-05 16:48:35.893 DEBUG 26901 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /AuthController/test.do
2019-06-05 16:48:35.894 DEBUG 26901 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/AuthController/test.do]
2019-06-05 16:48:35.894 DEBUG 26901 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/AuthController/test.do] are [/**]
2019-06-05 16:48:35.894 DEBUG 26901 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/AuthController/test.do] are {}
2019-06-05 16:48:35.894 DEBUG 26901 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/AuthController/test.do] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@4351bc9]]] and 1 interceptor
2019-06-05 16:48:35.894 DEBUG 26901 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor        : Skip CORS processing: request is from same origin
2019-06-05 16:48:35.896 DEBUG 26901 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2019-06-05 16:48:35.896 DEBUG 26901 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2019-06-05 16:48:35.896 ERROR 26901 --- [nio-8084-exec-3] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/a/gst25/AuthController/test.do] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

Comment: Remove your `DispatcherServlet` and the servlet registration. Add the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` to the `@ImportResource` instead. If you really want to use the `*.do` mapping add `server.servletPath=*.do` to the `application.properties`. I would just leave the default and try.

Comment: @M.Deinum - I did it and still getting same issue, for now removed the *.do refernce but still same issue, get below info in the log.

2019-06-05 15:32:18.094  INFO 15829 --- [io-8084-exec-10] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/AuthHandler/] onto handler 'authHandlercontroller'

Comment: You shouldn't mess around with your confiugraiton in XML. You shouldn't remove the `*.do` I was only refering to the mapping of the servlet not the stuff inside of it. Basically what you need to do is leave your configuration as/is, add the config to the `@ImportResource` and remove the 1 `@Bean` methods. Also what is loading your `views.xml`? That should be loaded as well.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, the views.xml is loaded via applicationContext-view.xml which is imported via applicationContextList.xml, please refer edited post with code.

Comment: And you are deploying to application or running it localy (with packaging as war?). Enable debug logging and figure out **what** gives the 404. Is it the controller or the view resolution. Also you are calling `AuthController.test.do` but your maping is `AuthController/*.do` so that won't match...

Comment: Posted the log in the post, please refer that. Seems some issue with view

Comment: No not really. It doesn't detect the correct handler. It delegates to the `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` which is basically a last resort trying to load static files. Try adding an `order` to  your `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` . 0 or 1 should do I guess.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum that solved the problem, there are other issues which I will look into.